# How do I configure SSRS server to only send a report server URL?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016, ssrs-subscription

I need to disable the option to attach a report in an SSRS subscription in SQL 2016. The only option that should be available is to send the report URL.

[SSRS Subscription Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UR7y.png)

I am curious how to perform the recommended method from MSDN to "configure the report server to send only a report server URL" found in this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160334.aspx.

I tried excluding a render format in my rsreportserver.config like this, but it didn't seem to do anything.

```
    <ExcludedRenderFormats>
      <RenderingExtension>PDF</RenderingExtension>
    </ExcludedRenderFormats>
```

I have a test SSRS 2016 environment installed using SSRS Native mode but if needed, I can uninstall and re-install if necessary with a non-default configuration.

Comment: I think that there are one or two checkboxes in the configuration for an SSRS subscription which indicate, some combination of whether or not the report output should be delivered and/or whether or not to include a link to the report in the email.

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to disable the check box to disallow attaching the email for all subscriptions.

Comment: Here's a link to a kludge workaround (it's rather old too) but take a read: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/97b5e59d-7e21-4742-84a3-e916820d68cb/ssrs-2008-subscription-shared-data-source-to-email-a-link-only?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159762.aspx): "_Delivery options that affect how the report is rendered and __whether the report is attached OR linked to the e-mail__ can also vary from subscriber to subscriber when the values are passed in from the row set._"

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to do at all. 

Did you look at the MSDN article I linked to? The suggested configuration is in there, however, HOW to make the configuration change in the rsconfiguration.config is not outlined in the article or any article that I could find.

Comment: Also, please look at the image that I included in my original post that shows what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. In the rsreportserver.config, find this element:

```
<Extension Name="Report Server Email" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.EmailDeliveryProvider.EmailProvider,ReportingServicesEmailDeliveryProvider">
```

Inside of that element is an element to add excluded file types. Just add **all** the supported file types and then the attachment option is effectively disabled.

```
                    <ExcludedRenderFormats>
                        <RenderingExtension>HTMLOWC</RenderingExtension>
                        <RenderingExtension>NULL</RenderingExtension>
                        <RenderingExtension>RGDI</RenderingExtension>
                        <RenderingExtension>PDF</RenderingExtension>
                        <RenderingExtension>MHTML</RenderingExtension>
                        <RenderingExtension>WORD</RenderingExtension>
                        <RenderingExtension>EXCEL</RenderingExtension>
                        <RenderingExtension>PPTX</RenderingExtension>
                        <RenderingExtension>IMAGE</RenderingExtension>
                        <RenderingExtension>WORDOPENXML</RenderingExtension>
                        <RenderingExtension>EXCELOPENXML</RenderingExtension>
                        <RenderingExtension>CSV</RenderingExtension>
                        <RenderingExtension>XML</RenderingExtension>
                        <RenderingExtension>ATOM</RenderingExtension>
                        <RenderingExtension>HTML4.0</RenderingExtension>
                    </ExcludedRenderFormats>
```

Finally, restart the SQL Server Reporting Services services.

Desired end result:

[image]